# Check if a folder is on a shared or local disk?

Tags: linux, local

How can I check if some folder in Linux is on a shared disk or a local disk?

Comment: What kind of shared disk is it? (Samba, NFS etc.) Can you give an example of the folder's path and also include the output of df if it's mounted.

Comment: I don't know. Only some disks are shared, some are physical, presented local

Comment: are shared network disk

Comment: Can you post the output of "df" here?

Comment: If you are asking a programming question this should stay on StackOverflow. If this is a question about how to do it from the GUI, command-line or other, then it should be moved to SuperUser or ServerFault

Comment: Given that my answer in terms of system calls and C coding was accepted, I think user710818 probably did intend this as a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell whether a folder is on a local disk by [looking up the filesystem type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7481322/184998). The first part of the answer is to find what filesystem contains the folder. To do that you need to find the filesystem using the `st_dev` field of the [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) information for the folder. (You can also do this by checking the folder path, but you then have to check every path element for symbolic links).

You can then cross-reference the `st_dev` field with the mount table in `/proc/mounts` using [`getmntent_r()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent). There's [an example of that in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337139/where-is-a-file-mounted/2337741#2337741). The `mnt_type` field will give you the text of the filesystem type, and you can compare the string with a list of network filesystems.

You can tell more information about FUSE filesystems by looking at the `mnt_fsname` field, but there are a lot of FUSE filesystems. You may want to treat them all as network storage. You'll have to make your own call about cluster filesystems such as GFS.